# File.Move() access denied ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, file, access-denied

In my web application I have to move a file from the user computer to the server.
I have to use an ascx component to do this.

Here is the code:

```
Private Function FileReplciate(ByRef FilePath As String)
     'FilePath  is the full file path e.g C:/Program Files/file.txt

      ' Create an id to hide the original file name (for security)

       Dim id = New Guid;

      Try

      'Here I move the file using File.Move()  here is the error
       File.Move(FilePath, Server.MapPath("temp\" & id.ToString))

      Catch ex As exception

      End Try

End Function
```

So when the source file is in a folder like "MyDocuments" or "MyPictures" or any sub folder
inside the "User" folder i got the access denied error.

When the source file is in folders like "C:\" or "C:\ProgramFiles" I don't get this error.

Comment: Already try, and get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you're getting an error in ASP.NET because an account your application is running under don't have appropriate permissions.

But what you've described is file uploading. Server-side code has no access to client machine file system, this is impossible. Client have to upload it from a location it wish. Use `<asp:FileUpload>` control for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for help. In fact I was using the file upload to do this, but in my application I have to do a copy of the uploaded file and this have to be done by an component not by an user. Have another way to do this.

Comment: @Guilherme: so you're moving an uploaded file. can't you place a file in proper place right after upload?

Comment: Yeah, I think that is the only solution. I was avoiding to do this because of some restrictions in my application, but will be forced to do this.
Thanks !